# Question next.js jest test run support commonjs compile error

Tags: next.js, jestjs, es6-modules, commonjs

## ErrorMessage

```
 FAIL  src/hooks/test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    /Volumes/T7/Project/2023/my_project/node_modules/lodash-es/isUndefined.js:22
    export default isUndefined;
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'



      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1505:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/configs/axios/instance.ts:1302:65)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/generated/swagger/Alarm/Alarm.api.ts:537:66)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/generated/swagger/Alarm/Alarm.query.ts:1149:27)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/hooks/useAlarm.ts:355:27)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/hooks/test.tsx:8:58)
```

## node_modules/lodash-es/isUndefined.js

```js
/**
 * Checks if `value` is `undefined`.
 *
 * @static
 * @since 0.1.0
 * @memberOf _
 * @category Lang
 * @param {*} value The value to check.
 * @returns {boolean} Returns `true` if `value` is `undefined`, else `false`.
 * @example
 *
 * _.isUndefined(void 0);
 * // => true
 *
 * _.isUndefined(null);
 * // => false
 */
function isUndefined(value) {
  return value === undefined;
}

export default isUndefined;
```

## test.tsx

```
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react';

import useAlarm from './useAlarm';

test('my first test', async () => {
  const { result } = renderHook(() => useAlarm, {
    wrapper: () => {
      return <div>test</div>;
    },
  });
});
```

The isUndefined.js file is being exported in the commonjs method.

Three methods have been taken to solve the corresponding error.

#### number 1

```json
// package.json
 "scripts": {
    "test": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
  },
```

#### Number two

This is how I added the plug-in to babel.config.js.

#### Number three

```js
// jest.config.mjs
moduleNameMapper {
...
"lodash-es": "lodash"
}
```

There is only method 3 among them.

I wonder if there is any other way other than method 3.

Comment: I still don't know how to reproduce .